# PrestaShop: Paypal module give error when buying

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm in dire need of help.

I've shop on PrestaShop 1.5.6.2 and PayPal module v 3.8.1 and when client accept payment there is this error:

[image]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess there was a misunderstanding :D. Wordpress 1.5.6.2 doesn't exists :). By the way, I guess you have to update the module to 3.11.1, if is possible obviously.

Comment: its not WordPress 1.5.6.2 it is PrestaShop 1.5.6.2 and it do exist. :)

Comment: Check discussion here: 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/292867-cant-create-new-order-error-thrown/

Comment: I think everything with ID's is ok. Becouse payment is processed and it does work. But everytime customer pays, it gives him this nasty error and sometimes they pay twice :) (More work for me :( )